# PHP: md5 генерирует разные значения

Tags: php, md5

Доброго времени суток.

Пытаюсь работать с API одного из сайтов.
Там нужно в GET запросе передать нужные параметры + те же параметры передать кодированными в md5.

если задаю переменную вручную $term  вручную
$term ="aktien";

запрос проходит отлично, но если ту же переменную считываю с ТХТ файла, то и API выдает ошибку и сам md5 код отличается

пример кода:

```
$cid="44";

$content = file('key.txt');

for ($z=0; $z < 2; $z++) {
    $term=$content[$z];
    //$term ="aktien";
    $sign = md5('cid='.$cid.'term='.$term.'/aso/suggestDNh8wdfgSFfsfSDNZx');

$url="https://сайт.ру/?term=$term2&cid=$cid&sign=$sign";

 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


$post = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($post);

}
```

Вопрос, из за чего возможны такие глюки? или что я делаю не так?

Кодировка везде utf-8

Comment: перевод строки , возврат каретки, пробел, табуляция
trim($var)

Comment: __file__ Возвращает файл в виде массива. Каждый элемент массива соответствует строке файла, __с символами новой строки включительно.__

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло, про пробел в начале строки не подумал, а вот перевод удалял таким способом $term =str_replace("\r", '',$term);
$term =str_replace("\n", '',$term);